# Why is TypeScript reporting that "'string' is not assignable to type 'RequestMode'"?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to use the Fetch API in TypeScript, but for some reason I am getting

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'RequestMode'.

Here is my code

```
export class MainService{
  constructor(){}
  request(requestObj){
    if (!requestObj.url) {
      return 'Please provide the end point url'
    }
    else {
     let requestParam = {
        method: requestObj.method ? requestObj.method : 'GET',
        headers: new Headers(),
        mode: 'cors'
      };
      fetch(endPointHost+requestObj.url,requestParam).then(function(resp){
                                        //^^^ error thrown here
        resp.json();
      })
    }
     console.log(" Reached request");
  }

}
```

The error reported is

> TS2345: Argument of type '`{ method: any; headers: Headers; mode: string; }`' 
>   is not assignable to parameter of type '`RequestInit`'. Types of property '`mode`' 
>   are incompatible. Type '`string`' is not assignable to type '`RequestMode`'.

Comment: Does `let requestParam: RequestInit = { …` work?

Comment: `requestObj.url === undefined && requestObj.url === ''` is a buf a variable cannot be `undefined` and `''` at the same time. try `if (!requestObj.url) { ... }` instead

Comment: @Ryan thanks Sir it worked, i am trying to find out the reason why it worked

Comment: @GuyWhoKnowsStuff I completely agree with you, that was my mistake, have make the change

Comment: sarcasm? :) i wasnt trying to answer just saw a bug

Comment: @GuyWhoKnowsStuff nope it was not sarcasm, actually you are right

Comment: The reason behind this is that TypeScript does a kind of limited form of type inference, so when you have the statement `let requestParam = { … };`, `requestParam` will always get the same type regardless of how it’s used later, and that type has `mode: string`.

Comment: The reason is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606183/how-can-i-hint-to-the-typescript-compiler-to-infer-string-literal-types-for-prop

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me: `mode: 'cors' as RequestMode,`

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is that `requestParam` could potentially be modified in an way that it does not respect `RequestInit` interface later.
You can either declare that `requestParam` implements `RequestInit` at creation:

```
let requestParam: RequestInit = {
    method: requestObj.method ? requestObj.method : 'GET',
    headers: new Headers(),
    mode: 'cors'
};
```

or put request parameters directly inside the `fetch` call:

```
fetch(endPointHost+requestObj.url, {
    method: requestObj.method ? requestObj.method : 'GET',
    headers: new Headers(),
    mode: 'cors'
}).then(function(resp){
    resp.json();
})
```