# TypeScript interface where object keys are values of another object

Tags: typescript

This is my interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
    a: string
    b: string
}
```

I have `objectA` from this interface:

```
const objectA: MyInterface = { 
    a: val1, 
    b: val2
}
```

I then have a function that reads an API response and creates a mapping as follows:

```
const createMapping = (response) => {
  const ret = {};
  response.forEach(item => {
    ret[objectA[item]] = true;
  })
 return ret;
}
```

Is there a way I can create an interface for the return value of `createMapping` such that the interface's keys are the value of `MyIterface`?

A return value could be `{val1: true}`, `{val2: true}`, or `{val1: true, val2:true}`

Comment: Have a look at how [advanced types (specifically with `keyof`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) work, and note that the type-checker runs at compile time, not run-time. As Aaron stated in his answer, you can't, so you'd need to run your own validation at run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure where `objectA` comes from, but you can get what you want.  First, wherever `objectA` comes from, you should let TypeScript know that the values are particular [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).  There are [different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47613767/2887218) to do this.  The most straightforward (but not DRY) way is to use type assertions:

```
interface MyInterface {
  a: string
  b: string
}

const objectA = {
  a: "val1" as "val1",
  b: "val2" as "val2"
}
```

Note that `objectA` is not being annotated as a `MyInterface`, since you don't want TypeScript to forget that its properties are `"val1"` and `"val2"`.  Its compatibility with `MyInterface` will be verified later.

Now we can make a function which takes anything `MyInterface`-like (with string properties) and produces a `createMapping()` function which uses it:

```
const makeCreateMapping = <O extends MyInterface & {[k: string]: string}>(o: O) =>
  (response: (keyof O)[]) => {
    const ret = {} as Partial<Record<O[keyof O], true>>;
    response.forEach(item => {
      ret[o[item]] = true;
    })
    return ret;
  }
```

The `O` parameter is the type of your `MyInterface` object.  Let's call `makeCreateMapping()` with `objectA`:

```
const createMapping = makeCreateMapping(objectA);
```

That's where the fact that `objectA` is a `MyInterface` comes in.  If it hadn't been, the compiler would have yelled at you.  Now if you inspect the type of `createMapping`, it is:

```
const createMapping: (response: ("a" | "b")[]) => Partial<Record<"val1" | "val2", true>>
```

That is, a function which takes an array of `"a"` or `"b"`, and returns a `Partial<Record<"val1" | "val2", true>>` which is essentially `{val1?: true, val2?: true}` whose valid values include `{val1: true}`, `{val2: true}`, and `{val1: true, val2: true}`.

To demonstrate:

```
declare const response: (keyof typeof objectA)[]
const mapping = createMapping(response);
mapping.val1 // true | undefined
mapping.val2 // true | undefined
mapping.val3 // error, doesn't exist
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! "Record" really did the trick and I got it working as I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

You would only get the API `response` values at runtime, at which point your TypeScript code has already been compiled away into JavaScript, so the answer is: no you would not be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I thought this was the case but just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify a return type or interface for the arrow function.

```
const createMapping = (response): MyInterface => {
  const ret = {};
  response.forEach(item => {
    ret[objectA[item]] = true;
  })
return ret;
}
```

In this case, when you execute the function `createMapping`, the output (`ret`) is expected to be of `MyInterface` type.

Comment: Yeah I have tried this earlier but it doesn't work. I can always write up another interface but was curious if there was another optimal way to handle this. Thanks though!