# Use object values as interface keys

Tags: typescript

I have an object containing property names in the form:

```
const INPUT_NAMES = {
    FIRST_NAME: 'first-name',
    LAST_NAME: 'last-name'
};
```

I want to generate an interface based on those property name values:

```
interface IPropertyFormat {
    [INPUT_NAMES.FIRST_NAME]: string;
    [INPUT_NAMES.LAST_NAME]: string;
}
```

That doesn't work because I am not using a literal type, nor a symbol and I get this: `A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.`

Using a simple constant like:

```
const KEY = "FIRST_NAME";

interface IPropertyFormat {
    [KEY]: string;
}
```

works but is not an elegant solution in my case and would like to avoid it if possible. I've checked out [this other kinda related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116691/typescript-interface-where-object-keys-are-values-of-another-object) but it doesn't provide a solution for my problem.

Anyone has any idea how to work around this problem?

EDIT:

Also, found a "some-what" solution [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65355784/8412959) once again using **const assertions**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Reverse map key-value type to value-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768302/typescript-reverse-map-key-value-type-to-value-key)

Comment: @Nishant I am not even sure how this is connected to my question in any way.

Comment: @zhulien maybe I have misunderstood, but does this solve your issue? https://tsplay.dev/rw2DYm it is the same thing in the duplicate question

Comment: @Nishant Yes, this is more like it. Thank you. Like I noted, the `const assertion` is of great aid and I wasn't aware of the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the correct litteral types in `INPUT_NAMES` you should use `as const`

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7&ssl=19&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAkgOQAoFUAqB9BBBAsgUQGUYBeGAbwCgYaYAxOAJUMxwIC4YByAMwEsATtAC0YAIYBbAKZcYYiDFCQoAGmq0AMthZY8%20TlwA28qKMky5CpdEoBfANyVKUAJ4AHKTEZSIAV0OwZBTqNADaANYwfGAwrh4gPPDI6LoEhBFSLgmx7lLZiKiseoQAuiWc0ALRAOZ2TnGe%20AAeHsBQUgAmpMG03PxCpuLSXBVQVWDVar1GJmbDo%20O1tk4dUsDGAp7WsE2cza3tHZSr62KbiuDQMC6c3n4BlAD0j-AxwPKed-6wYmBd%202tDnJzh0%20DweFJNmBYA0ICpYgALSGeADufEMhhgACNPL8YJCBCABJRtnI9i1AZ1ui4SZdYFjbj5vt0mkA)

```
const INPUT_NAMES = {
    FIRST_NAME: 'first-name' as const,
    LAST_NAME: 'last-name' as const
};

type Result =  {
    [k in typeof INPUT_NAMES[keyof typeof INPUT_NAMES]]: string
}

type Expected = {
    'first-name': string,
    'last-name': string
}

declare const x: Expected
declare const y: Result
// In case Result and Expected are different types, there will be an error
const a: Expected = y
const b: Result = x
```

If having an interface is very important:

```
interface myInterface extends Result {}
```

Comment: Thank you for the extended solution including an interface. As I'm having different types for the properties I would still have to build the interface manually specifying each type separately but now I have the means to do it more DRY-ish.