# In Typescript, how to use a string literal type in an interface?

Tags: typescript

The [duplicate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606183/how-can-i-hint-to-the-typescript-compiler-to-infer-string-literal-types-for-prop) is solving a slightly different issue. This one is specific to using a type within an `interface`.

---

I'd like to use a [string literal type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) in an interface. I'm sure that I'm a small change away from the answer to this.

Below is a simplified example of my code which shows the error.

What do I need to change to get `barFunction(baz)` to not have the below Typescript error?

```typescript
// foo.ts

type Name = 'a' | 'b'
interface Bar {
  x: Name
}

const n: Name = 'a'

const barFunction = (bar: Bar) => console.log(bar)

barFunction({ x: 'a' })

const baz = { x: 'a' }
barFunction(baz) // <-- error here
```

### Error Message

```
Argument of type '{ x: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Bar'.  
  Types of property 'x' are incompatible.  
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"a"'.
```

Screenshot of error message:

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I need to change to get `barFunction(baz)` to not have the
>   below Typescript error?

There is nothing you can do with `barFunction`. The problem is not there. It's in the fact your definition for `baz` got widened.

In order to mitigate it, use an explicit type definition:

```
const baz: Bar = { x: 'a' }
```

…or less ideal, but also a solution:

```
barFunction(baz as Bar)
```

With TypeScript 3.4 we will be able to also do:

```
const baz = { x: 'a' } as const
```

which will make TypeScript treat `'a'` as a string literal, not just any `string`.

Comment: Thank you. I also found that I can resolve error by using `barFunction(baz as Bar)`. It makes more sense to use your suggestion to cast type when creating `const` vs defining in function call so that the issue is solved in one place.