# Typescript stop object type from widening generic

Tags: typescript, types

```
const a =<T extends unknown>(arg:T)=>arg

const a_ = a(1) // type is 1

const b =<T extends unknown>(arg:T)=>({arg})

const b_= b(1) // type is {arg: number}, expect {arg: 1}

const c =<T extends unknown>(arg:T)=>({arg})

const c_= b(1 as const) // type is {arg: 1}, ok but degrade dev experience
```

In the example, if I return an object where the member type is based on the generic, it is widen back to `number` even if the generic type is `1`

problem solved if I give it const assertion, but it is not a good dev experience

How can I stop this widening behaviour?

Note: T must extends unknown

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvAHgCowKYA8obAEwhgFcwBrMEAdzAD4AKOAJwHMAuVASkVuZYFgAUENCRYcAPpJ49AIycYAekUwoATwAOGGAEsisoSPDQYAIyRpMOPIRLlKNBnw7cGAbz4BfTocGiTphKIZnIKyqqa2nowHqxsMGDEALamGEyeADRWWsCwsewwsp6+-rDAFujYuAREpBTUdIxxXDz0+d4lxmVBIbLwRKVhKupaukT58UVZIGRmxLD4GCxMcIswiwBu2Wk6eMAYQA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I hint to the Typescript compiler to infer string literal types for properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47606390/438273)

Comment: yes, seem like the answer is 'not possible'

Answer (score 0):

Just add the type to the function call

```js
const c = <T extends unknown>(arg: T) => ({arg})

const d: {arg: 1} = c<1>(1)

console.log(d.arg) // 1
```

In this way TS does not deduce the type from the argument (`number` in this case), it will use the type you give to him (`<1>`)

Comment: you are hardcoding the type with annotation, I need my type to be generic